# Decimal precision in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a column which represents money and can have 2 decimal places so i used :

```
'price' DECIMAL(2)
```

but after reading a bit i have seen things like :

```
'price' DECIMAL(6,2)
```

what is the difference between the 2?

what i want to have is any number of digits but limit the decimal ones to 2,is the first one right?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DECIMAL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html)

> In standard SQL, the syntax DECIMAL(M) is equivalent to DECIMAL(M,0). Similarly, the syntax DECIMAL is equivalent to DECIMAL(M,0), where the implementation is permitted to decide the value of M. MySQL supports both of these variant forms of DECIMAL syntax. The default value of M is 10

```
'price' DECIMAL(6,2)
```

> In this example, 6 is the precision and 2 is the scale. The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

```
'price' DECIMAL(2)
```

> If the scale is 0, DECIMAL values contain no decimal point or fractional part.

In other words: This field can have 6 digits of which 2 must be after the decimal point.

Comment: In other words: This field can have `6` digits of which `2` digits will be after the decimal point (`0000.00` - `9999.99`).

Answer (score 1):

As per **[mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html)**

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D) where

M: maximum number of digits

D: Number of digits to right of decimal point.

Refer : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html